# RGB2BGR in opencv does not convert colors correctly

Tags: image, opencv

```
pil_image = Image.open('1.png')
opencvImage = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pil_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

plt.imshow(pil_image)
```

Any reason why the `COLOR_RGB2BGR` does not convert the colors correctly?

I am trying to keep the red color but it changes it to purple.

Comment: Where's the purple please?

Comment: Oh, I see, you have joined the input and output image together. Please provide them separately.

Comment: Isnt it normal cos you are changing pixel order?

Comment: Why are you opening the image with PIL and processing it with OpenCV and displaying it with matplotlib? You'll surely confuse yourself and add unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: There's only a single image in your post that contains two diagrams.

Comment: Can you please post the **actual** `1.png` rather than a screenshot of how matplotlib thinks it might look with axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the image with PIL, like this:

```
im = Image.open('1.png')
```

you get an RGB image.

You then (needlessly) converted it to BGR, which OpenCV uses:

```
opencvimage = cvtColor()
```

but you display it with `matplotlib` which uses RGB!!!

I told you you'd confuse yourself

---

If you want to display an RGB PIL Image with PIL:

```
pRGB = Image.open('1.png')  # PIL RGB
pRGB.show()
```

---

If you want to display an RGB PIL Image with matplotlib:

```
pRGB = Image.open('1.png')  # PIL RGB
nRGB = np.array(pRGB)       # Numpy RGB
plt.imshow(nRGB)
```

---

If you want to display an OpenCV image with matplotlib:

```
nBGR = cv2.imread('1.png')
plt.imshow(nBGR[:,:,::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal situation. Because if your source image is in RGB format when you converted it to BGR, of course its channel order will change. So its normal.

For example:

```
if pixel of source = (12,102,53) = (R,G,B)  then this will become
                     (53,102,12) = (B,G,R)
```

**Note:** You can check your pixel values by using this [site](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html). Just change the order of channels then you will understand.

Here is also a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963283/python-opencv-imshow-doesnt-need-convert-from-bgr-to-rgb) discussed before.

Comment: PIL uses RGB ordering and OpenCV uses BGR, so it is necessary to re-order.

Comment: Then its simple too, Just need to one more conversion as ```CV_RGB2BGR```

Comment: No. If you run RGB2BGR twice you will end up where you started so there'd be no point to that.

Comment: But if you apply that opencvImage, you will get the desired color image which is an opencv format?

Comment: If you swap the first and third channels, and then swap the first and third channels again, you will get your original image back, so you might as well not swap anything at all... regardless of whether you had an OpenCV image or a PIL image or a CMY image or any other image to start off with.