# Imageio and cv2 Read Image - jpeg

Tags: python, opencv, python-imageio, image-augmentation

I am working on augmenting some images and I have run not necessary into a problem, but something that struck me as odd. For most of my augmentation methods I am using the [Imgaug](https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library and using `imageio.imread` to read my files. Though for my rotation augmentation I am using `cv2.imread`. I am using `cv2` because of a function I need to not loose any of the image when it is rotated ([`imutils.rotate_bound()`](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/)). Both methods work to read the image (jpeg), but I've noticed that the color changes with using the `cv2` method. Please see examples below. Is this something that I should be concerned about or ...?

[image]

**Edits:**
Just read through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963283/python-opencv-imshow-doesnt-need-convert-from-bgr-to-rgb) about `cv2`. Just to be clear, `cv2` is just stacking the bands in a different order? So unless I am adding bands from multiple images and not taking into consideration that band 1 from one image could be the Blue band and one band from another image could be the Red band, then I do not need to convert? The pixel values are the same, but how it is displayed is different?

Comment: `cv2` keeps colors as `BGR` instead of `RGB` and maybe you have to convert it. `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Comment: _Just to be clear, `cv2` is just stacking the bands in a different order?_ Yeah, but that's crucial for displaying. Matplotlib for example expects NumPy arrays to displayed to be RGB ordered, while `cv2.imshow` awaits images with BGR ordering. So, when mixing `imageio.imread` and `cv2.imread` you'll get different output results for any displaying method (Matplotlib, OpenCV). Please provide your code, so people can point to the exact location, where your "error" occurs.

Comment: Nevertheless, your linked Q&A is a proper duplicate target, so I'm voting to close this question as duplicate of [Python OpenCV - imshow doesn't need convert from BGR to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963283/python-opencv-imshow-doesnt-need-convert-from-bgr-to-rgb)