# Need help convert numpy array image to image with full color

Tags: python, numpy

Need help convert numpy array image to image with full color
I must use PIL because I will upload image to ftp server after this process done

[image]

Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python OpenCV - imshow doesn't need convert from BGR to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963283/python-opencv-imshow-doesnt-need-convert-from-bgr-to-rgb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cv2` uses BGR, `Image` uses RGB. So reverting the channel order would work

```
Image.fromarray(numpy_array[:,:,::-1].astype('uint8'))
```