# image.Mat in EmguCV is always in BGR format?

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

My code is all done thinking that the input `Mat` is in BGR format, so I am wondering if given an `Image` object in EmguCV, the property `Mat` from this object is always a BGR `Mat`. Otherwise, I would need to use `CvtColor` to get the BGR representation.

Example code:

```
byte[] data = GetPngPixelsArray(string); // Byte array in RGB format

Image<Rgb, byte> image = new Image<Rgb, byte>(width, height)
{
  Bytes = data
};

CvInvoke.Imshow("image mat", image.Mat);
CvInvoke.WaitKey(0);
```

The function I am using to get the byte array data:

```
internal static byte[] GetPngPixelsArray(string filename)
{
  byte[] rgbValues = null;

  using (var imageIn = Image.FromFile(filename))
  using (var bmp = new Bitmap(imageIn))
  {
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

    int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
    rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

    Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
  }

  return rgbValues;
}
```

In the example code above, the `Imshow` function is showing the image properly, and as far as I know `Imshow` always made a representation of the image using the BGR format.

So in fact the `image.Mat` is in BGR format, but I've checked the EmguCV documentation and haven't found any declaration that this is as I stated.

Comment: EmguCV is a wrapper around opencv. About opencv and BGR see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556545/why-opencv-using-bgr-colour-space-instead-of-rgb.

Comment: @wohlstad yes, I know that it is a wrapper around OpenCV, thanks for the link. But I am not asking why it is using BGR format. My code is all done thinking that the input image is a BGR image, so I want to know if `image.Mat` property is always represented as a BGR image. Othewise, I would need to use `CvtColor` to turn the RGB image to BGR. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I misunderstood then. Good question. You can consider to edit your question to emphasize this.

Comment: I checked in opencv c++, and it actually behaves differently. I created a `cv::Mat` with a rgb buffer all red, and opencv interpreted it as bgr. I.e. when I used cv::imshow I got a blue image. Are you sure your `data` is rgb ?

Comment: @wohlstad I edited my question to add the emphasis.

Comment: @wohlstad yes, I am using `Image.FromFile(string)` from `System.Drawing`, then creating a `Bitmap` from this image, and then reading the rgb values. Right now, I am thinking that when you create the `Image<Rgb, byte>` object, despite the `TColor` parameter you specify, it creates a `Mat` property, and this `Mat` is always in Bgr format (you specified that the `Image` is in Rgb, so the constructor can create the `Mat` in Bgr), but I can't confirm this behaviour since EmguCV docs don't states this, and I don't find it in the source code.

Comment: So it looks like `Image` is a EmguCV wrapper around cv::Mat that handles the conversions. I actually use opencv only in c++ environment, so I'm not familiar with EmguCV.

Comment: @wohlstad I edited the question and added the way I am getting that byte array. Yes, it seems like it handles automatically the conversion to BGR given the `TColor` parameter, and then the `.Mat` property is always in a BGR format. I would like to confirm this theory, but in the docs it doesn't appear, and I haven't found yet in the source code of EmguCV.

Comment: if `Image.FromFile` is merely calling `cv::imread`, then yes, it's always BGR, unless you specifically ask for grayscale or _all channels_ of the image.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz but how is generated the `.Mat` property when inside the constructor of the `Image`? That's what I've been searching in the source code of EmguCV to confirm that.

Comment: @wohlstad after all, it seems like my byte array was in BGR format. I will check my data array provider to understand why it is serving the array in BGR format. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just checked the behaviour of EmguCV creating an `Image` object, and the `.Mat` property has the same representation as the `Image` object, meaning that could be BGR or RGB.

I filled two vectors of size 750000 (500x500x3), this is what I've done:

```
byte[] rgbChar = new byte[750000];
byte[] bgrChar = new byte[750000];

for (int i = 0; i < rgbChar.Length; i+=3)
{
    rgbChar[i] = 255;
    rgbChar[i+1] = 0;
    rgbChar[i+2] = 0;

    bgrChar[i] = 0;
    bgrChar[i+1] = 0;
    bgrChar[i+2] = 255;
}

Image<Rgb, byte> imageRgb = new Image<Rgb, byte>(500, 500)
{
    Bytes = rgbChar
};
Image<Bgr, byte> imageBgr = new Image<Bgr, byte>(500, 500)
{
    Bytes = bgrChar
};

CvInvoke.Imshow("RGB Image", imageRgb);
CvInvoke.Imshow("RGB Image mat", imageRgb.Mat);
CvInvoke.Imshow("BGR Image", imageBgr);
CvInvoke.Imshow("BGR Image mat", imageBgr.Mat);
CvInvoke.WaitKey(0);
```

[image]

Edit: I would add some explanations, as it seems that the results are not self explaining.

I thought that the EmguCV `Image` class, **ever** was creating the `Mat` property as BGR. What means that?

If you check the `Image` creation, you need to specify the format, eg. `Image<Rgb, byte>`. I thought, that as you have to specify the format of the `Image`, that the `.Mat` property was a BGR representation of the RGB `Image`.

Basically, I thought that the behaviour was like that:

- `Image<Rgb, byte>` : -> Internal conversion from RGB to BGR into the `.Mat` property (Wrong).
- `Image<Bgr, byte>` : -> No conversion, the `.Mat` is BGR same as `Image`.

But the real behaviour, is that the `.Mat` property is just a `Mat` representation of the `Image`, doesn't matter if the `Image` is in RGB or BGR format, the `.Mat` property will be in the same representation.

This is the reason that in the two first cases the image shows blue (`Imshow` ever represents the image as BGR, if the image is in RGB it will show a blue image).

Comment: Actually it looks like the data is always interpreted as BGR (you wrote _the Mat property is not always in BGR format_). In `imageRgb` the first channel is 255, but it is interpreted as blue, not red. Have I misundertood you ?

Comment: @wohlstad I've just added a explanation of the results, can you check if now is understandable?

Comment: What you added is OK, but your answer starts with "... and the Mat property is **not** always in BGR format.". Why "not" in BGR ? Isn't it actually always assumed to be BGR ?

Comment: Maybe you should change it to something like: "the internal representation of the underlying `Mat` always assumes the data is BGR".

Comment: @wohlstad the `Mat` property of the `Image` class. Eg. `Image.Mat`, I was assuming that always was BGR, but I proved that is not always BGR, is just the same representation as the `Image`. I've added another explanation on the top.

Comment: Added another clarification. I think now it is clear.

Comment: @wohlstad sorry but I don't understand what you have just edited. The `Mat` doesn't assume the first channel is the blue, this is what `Imshow` function does, but that's not what I was testing here.

Comment: I don't think imshow does that. I believe imshow is a thin wrapper around c++ cv::imshow. I think the internal `Mat` (which encapsulates the c++ cv::Mat) is simply treating the data buffer always as BGR. That is what I saw in the test I did in C++, and it fits your result. However - as I wrote to you I am not much familiar with the EmguCV wrapper, so I might be wrong in this case. Feel free to edit again and modify.

Comment: Since I am not 100% certain, I removed the sentence I previously added to your answer.

Comment: @wohlstad check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963283/python-opencv-imshow-doesnt-need-convert-from-bgr-to-rgb , cv::imshow represents the `Mat` array as BGR, so I think `Mat` doesn't assume BGR format, this is what imshow does. In the case your `Mat` is in RGB format, as `cv::imshow` will assume BGR format, the image will be shown as blue.

Comment: I think it is a matter of interpretation. But anyway - what is the actual problem you are facing ? Eventually a cv::Mat holds data, and this data can be [mis]interpreted by imshow or any other mehod. If the data is BGR - opencv will work with it as is. If it is RGB (which only mean the first channel is red etc.), you can use cv::cvtColor(,...,CV_RGB2BGR) to swap the channels. BTW - note that `CV_RGB2BGR` and `CV_BGR2RGB` are defined to be the same. This is because cv::cvtColor only swaps first and last channels, it doesn't care if it's r<->b or b<->r. Is this not enough to handle your issue?

Comment: @wohlstad yes, I can face the problem with `cv::cvtColor`, but I needed to know if the `.Mat` was ever in BGR format, despite the `Image` format. Nevermind, right now my question is solved :)

Comment: Glad to hear. Sorry I couldn't assist more.